# How do you write the "estimate" equal sign?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm looking for a code, which can depict the estimate equal sign as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Other_related_symbols (6th sign: ESTIMATES).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Comment: Or something like `$\hat{=}$`

Comment: The [marvosym](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) package has a similar symbol called `\Corresponds`, but it's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 7):

The following summarizes many variants of the estimate symbol without changing *all* math symbols.

```
\newcommand*{\estimatesA}{\mathrel{\hat=}}
```

Source: Bernard's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170086/16967), Johannes_B's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170080/how-do-you-write-the-estimate-equal-sign/170101#comment391562_170080)

```
\newcommand*{\estimatesB}{\mathrel{\widehat=}}
```

Source: [DanteFAQ](http://projekte.dante.de/DanteFAQ/Symbole#13), Bernard's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170086/16967)

```
\newcommand*{\estimatesC}{\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}{=}}
```

Source: [DanteFAQ](http://projekte.dante.de/DanteFAQ/Symbole#13)
Remark: Recommended for `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` only, in the smaller styles, the `\wedge` becomes too large.

```
\newcommand*{\estimatesD}{\hateq} % MnSymbol
```

Source: Jukka K. Korpela's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170084/16967)

```
\newcommand*{\estimatesE}{\corresponds} % mathabx
```

Source: [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

```
\newcommand*{\estimatesF}{\mathrel{\text{\Corresponds}}} % marvosym
```

Source: Ian Thompson's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170080/how-do-you-write-the-estimate-equal-sign/170101#comment391564_170080)

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\estimatesA}{\mathrel{\hat=}}
\newcommand*{\estimatesB}{\mathrel{\widehat=}}
\newcommand*{\estimatesC}{\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}{=}}
\newcommand*{\estimatesD}{\hateq} % MnSymbol
\newcommand*{\estimatesE}{\corresponds} % mathabx
\newcommand*{\estimatesF}{\mathrel{\text{\Corresponds}}} % marvosym

\usepackage{marvosym,amstext}

\makeatletter

% \hateq from MnSymbol
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}
\@ifpackageloaded{MnSymbol}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolD}{}%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyD}{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{MnSyD}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}%
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
      <-6>  MnSymbolD5
     <6-7>  MnSymbolD6
     <7-8>  MnSymbolD7
     <8-9>  MnSymbolD8
     <9-10> MnSymbolD9
    <10-12> MnSymbolD10
    <12->   MnSymbolD12}{}%
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}{
      <-6>  MnSymbolD-Bold5
     <6-7>  MnSymbolD-Bold6
     <7-8>  MnSymbolD-Bold7
     <8-9>  MnSymbolD-Bold8
     <9-10> MnSymbolD-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolD-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolD-Bold12}{}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\hateq}{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{61}% 
\fi

% \corresponds from mathabx
% \usepackage{mathabx}
\@ifpackageloaded{mathabx}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}%
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
        <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
        <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
        }{}%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}%
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\corresponds}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"1D}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  A \estimatesA
  B \estimatesB
  C \estimatesC
  D \estimatesD
  E \estimatesE
  F \estimatesF
  G
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### OpenType fonts

LuaTeX and XeTeX support OpenType fonts. Package `unicode-math` supports OpenType math fonts. The symbol ≙ can then be used in different ways:

- Direct in put of the Unicode symbol: `≙`
- ASCII notation of the symbol: `^^^^2259`
- Command name (package `unicode-math`): `\wedgeq`

The following example shows the symbols from three OpenType math fonts (Family name/PostScript name/font name):

- Latin Modern Math/LatinModernMath-Regular/`latinmodern-math.otf`
- Asana Math/Asana-Math/`Asana-Math.otf`
- XITS Math/XITSMath/`xits-math.otf`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}%
  \newsavebox\BoxG\sbox\BoxG{$\wedgeq$}%
  %
  \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}%
  \newsavebox\BoxH\sbox\BoxH{$\wedgeq$}%
  %
  \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}%
  \newsavebox\BoxI\sbox\BoxI{$\wedgeq$}%
  %
  \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}%
}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\mathrel{\copy#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
  G \test\BoxG
  H \test\BoxH
  I \test\BoxI
  J
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result Unicode]

Comment: it's in unicode at U+2259, so it's in the stix and xits fonts, perhaps with the name `\wedgeq`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I have now added three OpenType math fonts that are supported by package `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 5):

Just with `\mathrel{\hat{=}}`. Or with `\widehat`if you like. More precisely:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\newcommand*\estimates{\mathrel{\hat{=}}}
\newcommand*\wideestimates{\mathrel{\widehat{=}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   & A \estimates B  \\
   & A \wideestimates B  \\
  & A = B
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or, maybe better, `\widehat`

Comment: I tried it and found it a little too large. But you're right, as it's a mattert of taste, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\hateq` from the `mnsymbol` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}
\begin{document}
$$a \hateq b$$
\end{document}
```

An alternative is to use `\corresponds` from `mathabx`, but it does not quite look right.

Comment: But [don't use `$$`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2417) in a LaTeX document!

Comment: It is better to avoid `$$..$$`, as per [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/13304)

Comment: Usual *caveat*: `MnSymbol.sty` (which is the correct name) changes ***all*** math symbols.

Answer (score 0):

There is a latex symbol for this : $\triangleq$

ref: http://ia.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:LaTeX_symbols

Comment: Is `\triangleq` used as an estimate equal sign? I rather know of the wedge form, as some users already suggested... This is a rather a comment than an answer.