# Best way for a ≙ symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I was wondering what the best way is to write ≙ in LaTex? I have used

```
\hat{=}
```

and

```
\widehat{=}
```

but somehow am not very satisfied with the looks. Is there an alternative ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried loading the `amssymb` package and typing `\triangleq`?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170101/31034

Answer (score 1):

The package `fdsymbol` offers `\hateq` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
\[
A \hateq B
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: This will change ***all*** symbols.

Comment: @egreg okay, is there an alternative then ?

Comment: @egreg Could you remind the method of extracting one symbol, please? I remember that you have already presented it on tex.sx.